# How to include files in an msi installer using wix?

Tags: installation, wix, wix3

I'm pretty sure that this is a basic question but I really don't know where to start... so any help would be really appreciated.

I'm creating an msi installer using WiX but how do you include, say an exe file, into the msi installer itself? I mean, when the msi installer is created, I want the exe file to be part of that installer so that when the user clicks on the msi on his machine, I don't need to look for the exe file from somewhere in the his system...

Hope I'm making sense...

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, my bad... was using copyfile with a wildcard inside a component... should have done the 1 component per file to include them.